# sys.time_zone_info's current_utc_offset in minutes format

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

In sys.time_zone_info of MS-SQL server current_utc_offset is stored in Hour Format(HH:MM).
There is any possible way to convert that time into Minutes format?
Actual Result

```
name                     |  current_utc_offset
---------------------------------------------------------
Syria Standard Time      |       +02:00
----------------------------------------------------------

Expected Result
name                     |  current_utc_offset        |  Minute
----------------------------------------------------------------
Syria Standard Time      |       +02:00               |     +120
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: What have you tried? Why didn't it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest way (avoiding creative string manipulation) is to (ab)use `SWITCHOFFSET`:

```
SELECT 
    name, 
    current_utc_offset, 
    DATEPART(TZOFFSET, SWITCHOFFSET('', current_utc_offset)) AS current_utc_offset_minutes
FROM sys.time_zone_info
```

If your really must have the sign with that in all cases and you can't handle that client-side (which I'd consider a better option), then `FORMAT` is your friend:

```
SELECT 
    name, 
    current_utc_offset, 
    FORMAT(DATEPART(TZOFFSET, SWITCHOFFSET('', current_utc_offset)), '+0;-0') AS current_utc_offset_minutes
FROM sys.time_zone_info
```

There are other approaches (`AT TIME ZONE` could be used on the time zone name, for example).